# In `titletoc` package, how to set the left margin in toc separately for numbered and unnumbered entries?

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I am using [`titletoc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc?lang=en) to creat ToC, and for some reasons, I want the space from the left margin `⟨left⟩` to be set differently for numbered and unnumbered entries. However, the current syntax

```latex
\titlecontents{⟨section⟩}[⟨left⟩]
{⟨above-code⟩}
{⟨numbered-entry-format⟩}
{⟨numberless-entry-format⟩}
{⟨filler-page-format⟩}
[⟨below-code⟩]
```

specifies it only for both entries together.

How to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the fields `numbered-entry-format` and `numberless-entry-format` can hold just about any horizontal material, you can just specify negative space.
Consider the following simple example:

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}
    [4em]
    {}
    {\contentslabel{1em}}
    {\hspace{-2em}}
    {\hfill\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A}

\mainmatter
\chapter{B}

\end{document}
```

[image]